# Two ways of finding symmetric trees through recurrsion

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, tree, binary-tree

A leetcode sum:
Given a binary tree, check whether it is a mirror of itself (ie, symmetric around its center).

For example, this binary tree [1,2,2,3,4,4,3] is symmetric:

```
      1
     / \
    2   2
   / \ / \
  3  4 4  3
```

But the following [1,2,2,null,3,null,3] is not:

```
    1
   / \
  2   2
   \   \
   3    3
```

Correct solution is:-

```py
class Solution:
    def isSymmetric(self, root: TreeNode) -> bool:
        if root == None:
            return True
        else:
            return self.Tsolution(root.left, root.right)

    def Tsolution(self, root1, root2):
        if (root1 == None and root2 == None):
            return True
        if root1 == None or root2 == None:
            return False
        else:
            return (root1.val == root2.val and self.Tsolution(root1.left, root2.right) and
            self.Tsolution(root1.right, root2.left))
```

My Question is why this code is wrong? It is also doing val check but in a seperate if condition.

```py
class Solution:
    def isSymmetric(self, root: TreeNode) -> bool:
        if root == None:
            return True
        else:
            return self.Tsolution(root.left, root.right)

    def Tsolution(self, root1, root2):
        if (root1 == None and root2 == None):
            return True
        if root1 == None or root2 == None:
            return False
        if root1.val == root2.val:
            return True
        else:
            return (self.Tsolution(root1.left, root2.right) and
            self.Tsolution(root1.right, root2.left))
```

This gives me error in second example of tree given above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, I got the answer.

```
      1
     / \
    2   2
     \   \
     3    3
```

When we reach to 2nd level of the tree, that is when root1.val == 2 and root2.val == 2, our function returns true by this condtion:

```py
if root1.val == root2.val:
            return True
```

and doesn't go down further down the fucntion .
Hence we should include this condition along with recursive call to left and right nodes like this

```py
 return (root1.val == root2.val and self.Tsolution(root1.left, root2.right) and
            self.Tsolution(root1.right, root2.left))
```